# Is there some android media player library?

Tags: android, video, media-player, m4v

Do you know some open source media player libraries for android ?
Or an open source android player app ?

I want to develop an app capable to play android m4v, I know Samsung galaxy Tab 7" is able to play them, but it's not officially supported by android.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

As far as I know it could be able to play m4v files without DRM protection

Comment: OK And is it true for all android version (including 1.5) ?

Comment: The MediaPlayer object itself is supported since: API Level 1 (It's specified in the docs), some methods on the MediaPlayer are available only on later versione, check the docs, the minimum supported api version is specified for each method in there

Comment: MediaPlayer does not support m4v. Here are the supported formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html